# Spring pass variables from one controller to another, but not as parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two methods in the Controller.
Once a form is submitted, a Controller that maps Post requests, calculates some values and redirects it to a GET controller that displays the view.

My Controllers:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/calculate",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView infoUser(@Valid InfoData info,BindingResult bindingResult) {

    long firstInfo=info.getFirstInfo();
    long secondInfo=info.getSecondInfo();
    /* service to find firstId and secondId */

    modelAndView.addObject("firstInfo",firstSurvey);
    modelAndView.addObject("secondInfo",secondSurvey);


    return new new ModelAndView("redirect:/information?firstId="+firstId+"&secondId="+secondId);;
}
```

And Get Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/information", method = RequestMethod.GET, params= { "firstId","secondId" })
public ModelAndView userView(@RequestParam(value = "firstId", required = true) String firstId,@RequestParam(value="secondId",required=true) String secondId) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("firstClient",firstId);
    modelAndView.addObject("secondClient",secondId);
    modelAndView.addObject("iD",firstId);
    modelAndView.addObject("iDsecond", secondId);
    modelAndView.setViewName("information");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

What I want to do is pass the firstInfo and secondInfo from infoUser() method and pass it on the method that maps Get methods, as an object so I can call it in an input field using thyemelaf.

```
 <input type="text" th:value="${firstInfo}" />
```

Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Rather than wrapping it up like that, it'd be better to use hidden fields--but remember that no matter what, you can't trust client input.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to remove parts of the code, so that it's more short and clear. But basically, when a form is submitted, in the controller, using the ID , I find the information of the user. But this is done in the first controller.
Now that information, I want to pass to the GetController so that I can pass it in my view from there.
Then the input type text that I have there, will be hidden .

Comment: You can't trust the client not to mess with that. You have to revalidate on every request.

Comment: I'm sorry . Revalidate what ? The user doesn't enter the ID , it is autogenerated. It is a hidden field on the form that is submitted, so that I know that's the user that submitted those data. ?
I'm not sure I understand you correctly.

Comment: It's not autogenerated if you send it to the client and the client sends it back as part of a different request. Anybody could fiddle with it in the browser dev tools. Never trust client input.

Comment: Ah. That's very true! Thank you so much ! I will look into ways to make it more secure. 
It's my first application in Spring, and I guess I didn't think it well through. Thank you again!